# Are there user profiles in Little Inferno on iPad?

Tags: ios, little-inferno

Being in a situation with several potential players for the same iPad, I would like to know if Little Inferno on iPad supports multiple profiles.

World of Goo had such possibility, and Little Inferno was made by the same people, so I would expect the same kind of setting.

Is it possible to have several user profiles (with different saves, user advancement)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ok, so I've bought the game on iPad.*

After the title screen, you have a screen with 3 chimneys, each of them for a different savegame.

[image: screenshot]

So yes, there are user profiles.